# how to remove div's top margin in bootstrap-4

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

how to remove div's top margin in bootstrap-4, `mt-0` class doesn't work and the custom css `margin-top: 0;` also not work.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-dark bg-primary mb-3 py-0">
      <div class="container">
        <a href="#" class="navbar-brand"
          ><span id="branding">A&K</span> Resturant</a
        >

        <button
          class="navbar-toggler"
          type="button"
          data-toggle="collapse"
          data-target="#navbarNavAltMarkup"
          aria-controls="navbarNavAltMarkup"
          aria-expanded="false"
          aria-label="Toggle navigation"
        >
          <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>

        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse mr-auto" id="navbarNavAltMarkup">
          <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a href="#" class="nav-link">Home</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a href="#" class="nav-link">About</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a href="#" class="nav-link">Services</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>

    <div class="h-75 bg-info mt-0"></div>
```

in the CSS file I make the body and html height 100%.

Comment: where you use `mt-0` class in div

Comment: The posted question does not appear to include [any attempt](https://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/) at all to solve the problem. StackOverflow expects you to [try to solve your own problem first](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/7630248), as your attempts help us to better understand what you want. Please edit the question to show what you've tried, so as to illustrate a specific roadblock you're running into in a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](/help/mcve). For more information, please see [How to Ask](/questions/how-to-ask) and take the [tour](/tour).

Comment: @MohitGupta in the second div

Comment: `container` div ?

Comment: @MohitGupta the last div in the code I mean

Comment: I want to remove the white space between the navbar and the div with classes of ```h-75 bg-info mt-0```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this html  on `nav` I change class `mb-0` and last div class change to `h-75 bg-info`

Use this below code.

```
       <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-dark bg-primary mb-0 py-0">
      <div class="container">
        <a href="#" class="navbar-brand"
          ><span id="branding">A&K</span> Resturant</a
        >

        <button
          class="navbar-toggler"
          type="button"
          data-toggle="collapse"
          data-target="#navbarNavAltMarkup"
          aria-controls="navbarNavAltMarkup"
          aria-expanded="false"
          aria-label="Toggle navigation"
        >
          <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>

        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavAltMarkup">
          <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a href="#" class="nav-link">Home</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a href="#" class="nav-link">About</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a href="#" class="nav-link">Services</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>

    <div class="h-75 bg-info">
Erat amet lorem magna amet stet et dolore. Ipsum est justo lorem takimata vero. Accusam invidunt takimata lorem ut lorem.
    </div>
```

Comment: And how to align nav-items to the right of the navbar ?